# How to create a Remote Aptitude/APT Repository?

Tags: package-management, apt, repository

I've recently started administrating more Ubuntu machines - as such I've had to recompile/create packages for our configuration. On my Redhat machines I was able to create a server that served as a Yum Repository - ensuring all my updates would be installed on the machines accordingly.

Is it possible for me to create an Aptitude Repository on a remote server? If so how would one go about doing so (and maintaining a custom/small set of packages on it - not just a mirror)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can either create a ppa on [launchpad](https://launchpad.net), or create your own apt repository on your own server. The recipe of how to build an apt repository can be found [here](http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/286).